# how can I filter a table by column?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to filter a table by column, this is the table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | filter: { person.lastName : lastName}">
        <td>{{row.person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.person.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.person.birthDate | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
        <td>{{row.person.balance}}</td>
        <td>{{row.person.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

The data looks like this:

```
$scope.rowCollection = [
              {person:{firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'}},
              {person:{firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'}},
              {person:{firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}}
];
```

How can I filter by column in this case last name? I can't get it to work when the json has more than 1 level.
plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/AFSoGw?p=preview

Comment: I changed filter declaration to this `| filter: {person: {lastName: lastName}}`, but on the begining table is empty - after you write something to input and delete it, it will work. I have no idea how to fix this first issue, so I can't say that I know answer ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer so it now only filters by last name, give it a try =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add that level to your search query's model, so the `ng-model` for the query input should be `person.lastName`

```
filter on lastname: <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
    <h3>Basic Smart-Table Starter</h3>
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>first name</th>
              <th>last name</th>
              <th>birth date</th>
            <th>balance</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | filter: {'person':person}">
            <td>{{row.person.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.person.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.person.birthDate | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
            <td>{{row.person.balance}}</td>
            <td>{{row.person.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

See this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UzFlP2JDFQoltmBFD3ZH?p=preview)

Comment: This does not search solely in the lastname column but also in the firstname.

Comment: thanks for noting me it, it should work as expected now

Answer (score 0):

Just have,

```
ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | filter: lastName"
```

it will filter your full array based on the value given by the user.

[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/O6mRuK/)

Comment: This filters all columns not just the last name column

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter by `lastName` you can simply update the filter call to reflect that with

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | filter:lastName">
```

This will filter `rowCollection` by `lastName`.

But if you want a stricter filter on specifically the last name I believe you'll be looking to define a more precise filter for your application. Something like `filterByLastName`, that will loop through the items and check through items which items have a last name matching that name.

Something along the lines of the following;

```
.filter('filterByLastName', function () {
  return function(items, lastName) {
    var filtered = [];
    if (lastName) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].lastName === lastName) {
          filtered.push[items[i]];
        }
      }
    } else {
      filtered = items;
    }
    return filtered;
  }
})
```

Hope that helps you out!